# What's the most eloquent way to post multiple,short message in android?

Tags: android, instant-messaging

I'm developing an instant message application in android.Say, a user want to send message to another user in the chat activity. There is a possible way to implement,that is

**Treat every message like a http post,and do the post  in another thread so that the network operation will not block main thread.**

But obviously,this is ugly and need a lot of resource. The user may want to send a lot of message in just one minute which means a lot of thread will be created and destroyed.Although a thread pool helps but I still think maybe there is a more eloquent way to do this.

Any constructive idea matters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use XMPP for Instant Messaging its already structured and constructive and its open source too..

Comment: @livemaker I neet to post every message to server. I just want to ask, is there any method to post multiple messages without so many threads created and destroyed in short time. Btw,xmpp protocol consumes too much bandwidth.

Comment: @livemaker. I decide to try mqtt protocol

Comment: mqtt is fine, But it isn't a structured format for IM, Mqtt is mostly used for IoT based application.

Comment: @吴环宇 you need to use websocket base connection for ur goal.

Comment: @duggu Yeah,another good idea